# Display text (in a div) based on radio button selection using Jquery / js

Tags: jquery

I've looked around and found a number of examples of this problem but I still can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to create a very simple version of a form that, in the future, will be more complex. Basically I have a number of "yes" / "no" radio buttons, and depending on the combination or replies, I want different texts to display. Formatting is absolutely not an issue here; I simply want this barebone problem solved and then I can probably figure the rest out.

```
<div class = "empirisk">

  <label for="prosthesis">Does the patient have a prosthesis?<br>
      <input type="radio" name="prosthesis" value="false" >
      <span>Ja</span>
      <input type="radio" name="prosthesis"  value="true" checked>
      <span>Nej</span><br><br>
  </label>

  <label for="sa_sannolik">Is s.aureus most probable?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sa_sannolik" value="false" checked>
    <span>Ja</span>
    <input type="radio" name="sa_sannolik"  value="true" >
    <span>Nej</span><br><br>
</label>

<label for="pc_allergy">Does the patient have a penicillin allergy?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="pc_allergy" value="false" >
  <span>Ja</span>
  <input type="radio" name="pc_allergy"  value="true" checked>
  <span>Nej</span><br><br>
</label>


<label for="type1">Is it a type-1 allergy?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="type1" value="false"">
  <span>Ja</span>
  <input type="radio" name="type1"  value="true" checked>
  <span>Nej</span><br><br>
</label>

</div>
```

So to start, I want the last group of checkboxes (type_1) only be displayed if the reply is "yes" in the previous group (pc_allergy). Otherwise it stays hidden.

Other than that, I want a text displayed based on the values of the different checkboxes. There aren't 16 permutations since some combinations result in the same treatment. But I'd like a way to traverse through all selections perhaps with case-loop or something similar. At least that's what I tried and failed with...

So for the show/hide part I tried:

```
  $('.pc_allergy input[type="radio"]').change(function() {

      var checked = $('input[name="pc_allergy"]:checked').val();

      if(checked){
        $('type_1').show();
      }else{
        $('type_1').hide();
      }

  });
```

And I get it to start hidden and then display when I click yes. But it doesn't disappear when I click no again.

What I would like to do, obviously, is create one function that runs every time a user clicks any of the radiobuttons and loops through each and every one of them, saving the results in an array and then a case-loop to determine what to output.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll find a browser's debugger tools useful (or even console.log()) to find out if the values you are getting are what you expect. For example, `.val()` will always return a String, because form input values are always Strings. So your variable `checked` is always truthy, because it's either the string 'true' or the string 'false'.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio][name=pc_allergy').change(function() {
    if (this.value == true) {
        // ...
    }
    else if (this.value == false) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Grumpy. I got it to work with that code. Just had to edit this.value == true, to this.value == "true" then it worked!